# RubyMine Stops in Library Source Code Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine to debug a rails app I am working on. For some reason when I run my my app rubymine stops at "invisible" break points inside of library source code. For example, I hit server.rb line 92 in railties, rack/server.rb line 190 in rack, logger.rb line 315, etc.

I am using the built-in debugging gems from RubyMine. I have uninstalled the byebug gem so there shouldn't be any conflicts that I know with regards to that issue.

I am using ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.2.1.

How do I go about fixing this problem so I am only hitting break points in my app?

Comment: You could try to delete your .idea directory from the project root. It contains the breakpoints for the app, and will be automatically regenerated when the project is opened. Submitting as a comment instead of an answer, for now, as it's a bit of a shot in the dark...

Comment: View Breakpoints Did you try this command Ctrl+Shift+F8 (Windows) or Shift ⌘ F8 (Mac OS) Then try to delete all break points.

Comment: @BradWerth That didn't work, but it was a great idea.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I tried this as well, but these aren't really break points, but they act as a break points and I keep hitting these library files.

Comment: Check debugger gems versions (ruby-debug-ide and debase), looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16915

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RubyMine 7.1.4 and debase 0.1.6 this problem occurs. The problem is solved by using debase 0.1.7. Go to the RubyMine Gem Manager update debase to 0.1.7 and the problem should be solved.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16915 for the JetBrains issue.